# Gulp generate index.js of all files in folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm working on a nodejs project using gulp and browserify.

I want to include a folder of modules of which I don't know the filenames in my main js file.

My initial thoughts on how to approach this are:

1. run a gulp script to create an index.js file for all the files in the folder
2. require the generated index.js file in the main browserify file
3. run browserify

Example:

dir structrure:

```
/
  /models
    /model1.js
    /model2.js
```

desired ouput object:

```
{
  "model1": {...},
  "model2": {...}
}
```

where {...} is the object exported by the file using module.exports.

Is this the right approach? Are there any better ways to approach this?

And if this is the right approach, I'm not sure how to achieve it using gulp (creating an index file), so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rik

Answer (score 2):

Browserify only has one entry point - it will then walk down the dependency tree of you entire app and include them as required.

#### Let say you have a folder structure like this:

- public

  - index.html
  - js

    - main.js
    - someother.js
    - another.js

#### And you only want to include a single js file from you html called bundle.js

#### Your gulpfile.js would look something like this.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
        entries: './js/main.js',
        debug: true,
        cache: {}
    });

    var rebundle = function() {
     bundler
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .buffer()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
    };
    bundler.on('update', rebundle);
    return rebundle();

});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);
```